# Typing ऋ़ alongside consonant for typesetting Devanagari doc with xetex in OSX

Tags: xetex

I'm trying to type the word `जृ़ष् वयोहानौ` into my document (using TexShop) on OSX. The sequence of keystrokes for QWERTY keyboard to produce `जृ़` is <kbd>j</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>
While I can type this in a browser, TexShop converts what I type into `जृ` i.e ज् followed by short ऋ

Has anyone encountered a similar problem? If so, what's the solution? A fully-working example of my attempt is below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari]{Sanskrit 2003}
जृ़ष् वयोहानौ
\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't this just a "how do I input these characters into my computer" question that has nothing to do with XeTeX?

Comment: You are right :=) I asked the question here since some users here have experience with inputting devanagari and may offer a solution to my problem

Comment: Cool, you can use the online transliterator you found, or [this](http://www.learnsanskrit.org/tools/sanscript) or [this](http://shreevatsa.appspot.com/sanskrit/transliterate.html) or use [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele) to create/edit your preferred keyboard layout.

Comment: I have personally not typed vedic svaras, but I'm sure it's possible… see if any of the entries in Vishvas's list [here](https://sites.google.com/site/sanskritcode/home/survey#TOC-Script-and-Input) helps. And you can email me at `s…a@gmail.com` (fill in the `…` with the rest of my name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I couldn't find the right set of characters on OSX to print `ॠ` or 
`जॄ`, I have found a workaround using itrans' online tool for converting text encoded in itrans into devanagari.

1. Lookup the itrans mapping for `ॠ` from http://www.aczoom.com/itrans/html/tblall/node2.html
2. Type in the characters in the left window and observe their unicode equivalents on the right.

[image: Converting itrans to unicode]

3. Copy the unicode text into your document.